# how to get rid of non-fast-forward error message in a git branch?

Tags: git, branch

I forked a branch A from master. Then after some time I forked another branch B from branch A.
Now, whenever I push code onto branch A I see the message below. How can I get rid of it?

```
   ff65b4e..304e3f6  A -> A
 ! [rejected]        B -> B (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxx'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git log --all --graph
* commit 304e3f60363fe734fc4eebab79b23a1dc6528ea3
| Author: xxxx
| Date:   xxxxxxxx
|
|    xxxxxxxxxx
|
* commit ff65b4e3ae91117f8ffb12a60ada81f888a94275
| Author: xxxx
| Date:   xxxx
|
|     xxxx
```

Comment: Did you read the error? Specifically the lines marked **hint**? It's telling you exactly what to do to fix it.

Comment: I do not really want to merge the 2 remote branches. I want the branches to have their separate existence. And I did a git pull on both the branches before doing a git push on branch A

Comment: whoever downvoted can you please specify the reason. If it is because the assumption is that I did not follow the hint in the message, that is not the case.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us the output of `git log --all --graph`? Git **definitely** thinks the remote has commits on branch B that you haven't merged with

Comment: How are you doing the push? You don't *need* to push both A and B. If you only want to push A you can do that.

Comment: @Gareth - added the output

Comment: @Klas - I just git "git push" when I am on the branch A window

Comment: Normally when you do `git push` you only push that branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout B
git pull
```

Fix any conflicts

```
git push
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but I did do a git pull on branch B and there are no conflicts there.